# VC++ optimisations break comparisons with NaN?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, ieee-754

IEEE754 requires NaNs to be unordered; less than, greater than, equal etc. should all return false when one or both operands are NaN.

The sample below yields the correct `F F F F F T` as expected when compiled using g++ at all optimisation levels, and when compiled using  VC++'s CL.exe (32-bit version 15.00.30729.01) with no optimisation arguments or any combination of /Od, /fp:fast, /arch:SSE.

However, when compiled with /O1 or /O2 (and any/no other optimisation arguments), `T T F F F T` results, even with /Op also specified.

The 64-bit version of CL.exe yields many variations - `T T F F F T`, `T T T F F T`, `T T T F F F` etc - depending on optimisation level and whether /fp:fast is specified, but as with the 32-bit version, compliant behaviour only seems to be possible with all optimisation disabled.

Am I making some obvious mistake? Is there some way to cause the compiler to comply with standards here without sacrificing all other optimisation?

```
#include <limits>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char const ** argv )
{
    float test = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();

    printf( "%c %c %c %c %c %c\n",
            (test < test) ? 'T' : 'F',
            (test <= test) ? 'T' : 'F',
            (test == test) ? 'T' : 'F',
            (test > test) ? 'T' : 'F',
            (test >= test) ? 'T' : 'F',
            (test != test) ? 'T' : 'F'
        );

    return 0;
}
```

An example `build.cmd` that reproduces the problem:

```
set "PATH=c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\amd64;c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7;c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE"
set "LIB=c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\lib\x64;c:\program files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib\x64"
cl test.cpp /fp:fast /Od /c /I "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include"
link "/LIBPATH:C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/vc/lib/amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\/Lib/x64" /DEBUG /IGNORE:4199 /IGNORE:4221 /MACHINE:X64 /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE  test.obj
test
```

**EDIT**

For the record, the example originally given in the question used

```
inline float QNaN()
{
    static int const QNaNValue = 0x7fc00000;
    return *(reinterpret_cast<float const*>(&QNaNValue));
}
```

to generate a NaN; as a number of comments and answers point out, this is undefined behaviour, and replacing it with std::numeric_limits::quiet_NaN() actually fixed the issue for some versions of the 32-bit CL.exe

Comment: I suspect it may have something to do with the undefined behaviour caused by treating an `int` object as a `float`. Have you tried `0.0 / 0.0` instead?

Comment: The QNaN function has undefined behaviour. Have you tried [using the C++ facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/quiet_NaN) to get a NaN instead?

Comment: That's a total red herring, I'm afraid (the original problem I encountered was rather more complex than this simple example I narrowed it down to). I have edited the sample to use the standard library function suggested in comments instead, the results are unchanged.

Comment: That's not a NaN anyway, because IEEE requires a NaN's significant to be non-zero. (Note: OP's original code used a reinterpret cast on 0x7fa00000)

Comment: I can reproduce this in cl 15.0, but it appears fixed in cl 16.0.

Comment: @Martinho: awesome - good to know I can put /fp:fast back we go to that

Answer (score 5):

So, to summarise, there were a number of separate issues:

- the original example code yielded undefined behaviour by violating strict aliasing. Fixing this was sufficient to resolve the problem for some versions of the 32-bit compiler.
- with that issue fixed, removing `/fp:fast` resolved the problem for all versions of both the 32-bit and 64-bit compilers available to me
- Martinho mentions that the problem no longer exists in cl 16.0 even with `/fp:fast`

Answer (score 4):

You're invoking undefined behaviour by casting an `int*` to `float*`. I've tried your code with VS 2010, using `std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN()` instead of the cast, and it gave the expected result (all but the last one were `false`) with `/O2` and `/fp:fast`.

**UPDATE**

I've copy-pasted your revised example into both VS 2010 and VS 2005. In both of these, the 32-bit compiler produces correct results (`F F F F F T`), while the 64-bit compiler does not.

Comment: Hm. What compiler version? I attach one example set of build commands that reproduces the incorrect behavior for me with std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN()

Comment: Hm. Using the library function, *and* omitting /fp:fast, yields correct behaviour for all cases (32-bit and 64-bit builds, all optimisation levels) here. I'll go with that :)

Comment: @moonshadow why don't you post that as an answer instead of accepting one that doesn't solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

That's because the QNaN function invokes UB by violating strict aliasing. The VS compiler is well within its rights to produce any behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the `/fp:strict` option.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e7s85ffb.aspx

You may also want the `float_control` pragma.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/45ec64h6.aspx

All this was right in the documentation under "Compiler options by category"

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/19z1t1wy.aspx

Comment: The issue has been resolved above, but for the record, none of `/fp:strict`, `/fp:precise`, or any of the pragmas help here.

Comment: @moonshadow, it's not clear from the comment trail above: "I have edited the sample to use the standard library function suggested in comments instead, the results are unchanged". So it seems the issue isn't resolved. Did you try `/fp:strict` with your previous `QNan()` function? Just trying to clarify.